# php include from localhost on other port

Tags: cross-domain

I am building a php desktop managment site for WIndows because I am a lot outdoors but I can't succeed in including the transmission-qt webinterface. I tried changing `.htaccess $.ajax GET` and `$.ajax PUT` but I still get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:// localhost:8123/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:// localhost:8010' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I include it without using a `iframe`?

The transmission port is 8123 and the webserver port is 8010

Comment: Sorry, you need to provide much more information about your setup. We cannot _guess_ your environment.

Comment: @arkascha What do you mean with the setup information?

Answer (score 0):

I think your server in localhost:port must send a response header allowing cross domain.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS